# Execute SSIS pacakge using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I want to execute SSIS Package using stored procedure, I am using SQL Server 2014, I am getting error on my SP .

Code:

```
Alter procedure ExamplePackage
@output_execution_id bigint output
as
begin
declare @execution_id bigint  
DECLARE @BranchErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @ContractDateErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @ContractNoErrorMessaget nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @CreatedBy bigint
DECLARE @DatabaseConnection nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @DSA_IDErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @DSACodeErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @FileDiscriminator nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @FileName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @FinAmountErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @IsDeleted bit
DECLARE @ProductCodeErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @ProductErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SourceFilePath nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SubProductCodeErrorMessage nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @TFlexTypeId bigint
DECLARE @WorkRequestId bigint

exec ssisdb.catalog.create_execution 
@BranchErrorMessage = 'Branch code does not exist in Branch Master'
,@ContractDateErrorMessage = 'ContractDate is Empty',
@ContractNoErrorMessaget='ContractNo is Empty',
@CreatedBy='2' ,
@DatabaseConnection='Data Source=SAMDK12120010;User           ID=sa;Password=jgd123$;Initial      Catalog=TataCapitalTest6_May;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Auto Translate=False;',
 @DSA_IDErrorMessage='DSA Id is invalid',
  @DSACodeErrorMessage='DSACode is Empty',
  @FileDiscriminator='IntermediateError',
   @FileName='ss',
    @FinAmountErrorMessage='FinAmount is Empty',
     @IsDeleted='False',
     @ProductCodeErrorMessage='ProductCode is Empty',
     @ProductErrorMessage='Product code/SubProduct code does not exist in      Product Master',
      @SourceFilePath='D:\Vinoth Kannan\Package    new\ODS_CLMS_DAILY_DISBURSED_CASES_PLBL_17012016-15.01.txt',
     @SubProductCodeErrorMessage='SubProductCode is Empty',
     @TFlexTypeId='20',
       @WorkRequestId='200',
     @package_name = 'DisbursePLBLCaseIntermediateImportPackage.dtsx'
      ,@execution_id = @execution_id output
      exec ssisdb.catalog.start_execution 
     set @output_execution_id = @execution_id
      print @output_execution_id
          end
```

I am getting error:

> sg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure ExamplePackage, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'ExamplePackage' expects parameter '@output_execution_id', which was not supplied.

Example of SP call:

```
Exec ExamplePackage
```

Comment: Post also how you call your ExamplePackage SP.

Comment: Getting Error like Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Procedure execute_ssis_package_sample, Line 6
Database 'ssisdb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the `ssisdb` database doesn't exist.  I would check on that if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Call procedure with parameter

```
DECLARE @output_execution_id bigint
EXEC ExamplePackage @output_execution_id OUTPUT
```

Inside your procedure you have to call create_execution first to get execution ID. 
Than set your parameters and finaly call start_execution with that execution ID.

Learn here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034.aspx

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@output_execution_id".

Comment: EXEC ExamplePackage @output_execution_id OUTPUT getting error

Comment: Yes, you "Must declare the scalar variable @output_execution_id" :)

Comment: Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Procedure ExamplePackage, Line 25
Database 'ssisdb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: Getting Error Like this

Comment: Did you checked if 'ssisdb' exists? Please, read error message first and try to act on it. You are the only one who has acces to your server.